# Subview getting clipped by its parent view when scale transformation done -Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, quartz-graphics, catransform3d

My project involves ***4 independent views in screens***. In this case,apple documentation states us to have only *one viewcontroller and have 4 NSObject* to control the different views.I didnt  use Interface builder to create the views and NSObject, I didnt by declaring programmatically. In one of the view I have all my images loaded up using imageview as their subview.

What I`m trying to do is trying some animation similar to mac os dock like animation. zooming in when touched.

> Problem is when i`m zooming the images
>   when the view is being touched. I used
>   CATransform3dMakeScale. My imageview
>   is being clipped by the parent view.
>   Can you help me out in this. I guess I
>   must have missed some flag.

I trid clipstobounds, and resizing flags. Nothing works.

My suspection whether the problem may be because of the following reasoens but i don`t know how to debug it

1) Since I created NSObject without using viewcontroller. Did I miss any of the flags that will be automatically set during loadView or init method.
2) I also have doubt whether the way in which I have used the NSObject is correct or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found answer for this. My subview was below another view whose background was clear color. Hence it appeared to be clipped. I cleared this problem by using [uiview bringsubviewtofrom:]